# File upload on Swagger Editor OpenAPI 3 not showing the file browser when trying it out

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor, openapi

I'm using Swagger Editor with OpenAPI 3.0. I need to document a route which consists of uploading an image. When attempting to "Try it out", I don't get the file browser to choose the image to upload in the request body, all I get is a JSON string with the name and type of parameter.

[image: File Upload "Try it out" screenshot]

This is the YAML description of the route:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...
paths:
  /media/upload/thumbnail:
    post:
      tags:
        - media
        - publications
      security:
        - bearerAuth: []
      summary: upload a kid's publication
      operationId: uploadPublication
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                upload:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  id:
                    type: string
                    description: ObjectId of the uploaded file in db (original size)
                    example: 5a6048b3fad06019afe44f24
                  filename:
                    type: string
                    example: myPainting.png
                  thumbnail:
                    type: string
                    description: ObjectId of the uploaded file in db (thumbnai size)
                    example: 5a6048b3fad06019afe44f26
        '400':
          description: Authentication failed
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Your definition is correct.

Support for file upload for `multipart/form-data` requests in OpenAPI 3.0 definitions has been added in Swagger Editor 3.5.7 and Swagger UI 3.16.0. Make sure you are using a version that supports file upload.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my same kind of concern !!!
I had to modify the input type to requested endpoint method.
**Note-** It might not address all type of requirements, but few can definitely be benefitted from this

**Before:**

```
/myEndpoint( @RequestBody RequestModelName requestModelName )
```

where RequestModelName has properties and getter/setter...

1. private MultipartFile file
2. private String otherProp

By this I could NOT see File option in swagger.

**After:**

```
/myEndpoint( @RequestParam MultipartFile file, @RequestParam String otherProp )
```

And then I could see File option in swagger...

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```yaml
content:
          image/png:
            schema:
              properties:
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
```

Comment: Agree this would be a simpler solution. **However**, in its current form your answer doesn't explain *why* OP should use your solution instead of multipart form requests.